# Azure AD B2C for API with sign in and sing up with API (not html page)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Ok, done I could finally setup my AD B2C with my web API and with Postman. To do so I followed instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.2.).

Now, in Postman when I click "Get New Access Token" in Authorization tab the system redirect me to the HTML sign in/up page from Microsoft and I need to enter my credential. I don't want that. I want to use a predefined login, password because I want to simulate the sign in/up using API only. something where I use the body or header to send my credentials and get the token.

I think I should play with the Grant Type property. Is it correct?

---- EDIT 1 ----

I found [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc) and I did this

[image]

But it is not working and I don't know what to put in Client Secret. Here is my Postman log

[image]

Also I wanted to show this in case this can be relevant:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to sign in on postman like [Sign In](https://imgur.com/a/2qvqYIc) and then [Get Token](https://imgur.com/a/zwrB1Re)

Comment: I would like to Get Token by passing my credentials without having to call the Sign In HTML page. I want to create a in-app login system and just use B2C as a classic OAuth Get Token system.

Comment: You have to fetch your secret from your B2C tenant application keys [see here](https://imgur.com/a/9Kcxh7s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you must [create a resource owner password credentials (ROPC) flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc#create-a-resource-owner-user-flow), which enables credentials to be POSTed from Postman to Azure AD B2C's token endpoint.

Also, you must [register Postman as a native client application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc#register-an-application), so that it can use this ROPC flow.

Then, in Postman, you can enter the following settings:

- **Grant Type**: `Password Credentials`
- **Access Token URL**: `https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{your-ropc-policy-name}/oauth2/v2.0/token`
- **Client ID**: Set to the client identifier for the Postman application
- **Client Secret**: Set to an empty string
- **Scope**: `openid {your-postman-client-id} {any-api-published-scopes}`
- **Client Authentication**: `Send client credentials in body`

Comment: I suppose the {your-policy-name} is the name of my User flows (policies): B2C_1_ROPC for me.

Comment: And what about the scope? On create a resource owner password credentials (ROPC) flow page information seems a little bit different from you. Do you know why? I'm testing different settings at this moment. I will add my results and log information when I have more data.

Comment: Hi @BastienVandamme. I've added the above answer for the policy name and the scope values.

Comment: I added my postman log. I'm also not using your URL. I think I need to use the one from token-endpoint like explained here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/06/13/testing-b2c-resource-owner-password-credentials-ropc-policies-using-postman/, right?

Comment: This **AADB2C90224** error is occurring because you must register the Postman app in Azure AD B2C as a native client. (Only a native client app can invoke an ROPC flow.) If Postman is already registered, then ensure **Include native client** is set to **Yes** in the application properties.

Comment: I guess all this is about security. ROPC should not be the way I get a token. I should always call a third service to give me the token. Now I have a
AADB2C90117: The scope 'user_impersonation' provided in the request is not supported. Ok fixed and working by just removing it.

Comment: Fixed for Postman but I think I should do more investigation about security and this ROPC flow. My idea by using this B2C system is to delegate the login to openid website like Facebook but I also want to allow user to login directly if they don't have any Facebook account or don't want to link with it. I also found this https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications and I don't know what to think now.

Comment: I think you should delegate the credential collection to Azure AD B2C in the popup window.